# WEBスクレイピングのログイン処理

Tags: html, css, vba, web-scraping, selenium

WEBスクレイピングでログインまで自動化したいのですが、ログインボタンの要素が見つからず困っています。
canvas要素上の処理であることは確認できましたが、どうログイン処理を記述するかで詰まりました。
座標を具体的に指定して組めはしましたが、異なる端末環境で使用する予定の為あまり意味がありません。
JSから数値取得して座標指定するといったことはできるのでしょうか？
VBA/SELENIUM環境です。
また具体的に良い方法があれば教えて下さい。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 書きかけでも構わないので実際のコードや、該当ページの情報が無いと具体的な回答が難しいように思います。

Comment: 「要素上の処理であることは確認できました」であれば、「VBA/SELENIUM環境」でのコードが書けそうですがどこで困っているのでしょうか？「また具体的に良い方法があれば教えて下さい。」とありますが現状の情報からでは”具体的”なアドバイスをもらうのは難しいかと思います。どのようなhtmlなのか提示お願いします。

Comment: こんな記事が参考になるのでは？ [Relative Locators](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators/#relative-locators)

Comment: あるいはこんな記事を参考に、moveToElementとclickでcanvas(の中心?)とcanvas内でのボタンの相対位置を指定してマウスクリックのシミュレートをすれば良いのでは？ [How to find the coordinates of the buttons on a canvas, and click on them after using Java and Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59918530/9014308), [Selenium のアクション クラス – マウス クリックとキーボード イベント](https://www.guru99.com/ja/keyboard-mouse-events-files-webdriver.html), [Selenium: How to click at x,y coordinates?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/8535), [Is there a way of clicking an specific point/element in a canvas (with javascript, jquery or selenium)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42821375/9014308)